# Can't use new instance with custom JFileChooser: not having a constructor?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

This is not my program, but no one had this problem yet, i'm the first one, so the original dev already tried to help me, but was unable to help, as the program works fine to everyone else.

I need to click on a Button, ant this button was supposed to show a pop-up to select a file (JFileChooser), but on everyone pcs it works fine as heck, but on mine it doesn't, noting happens, no popup, just the error on the debugger.

the program has a debugger,  that is the code that create the error log :

```java
      return (T)clazz.getConstructor(new Class[0]).newInstance(new Object[0]);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException("No default constructor found for " + clazz.getName());
    } 
  }
```

/\
this is what creates the log.

---

this is the problem described in the debug log:
/

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: `
No default constructor found for com.github.manolo8.darkbot.gui.tree.components.JFileOpener
```

---

I've already installed the correct sdk and runtime, the one that everyone is using, and they had no problem.

this is the code inside the file: "JFileOpener"

```java
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class JFileOpener extends JLabel implements OptionEditor {
  private final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File("."))
    {
      protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent) throws HeadlessException {
        JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        return dialog;
      }
    };

  public JComponent getComponent() { return this; }

  public void edit(ConfigField field) {
    setText(Strings.fileName((String)field.get()));
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
          if (this.fc.showOpenDialog(null) != 0)
            return;  field.set(this.fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
          setText(Strings.fileName((String)field.get()));
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a default constructor you `JFileOpener` class? Just to see what it happens?

```
public class JFileOpener extends JLabel implements OptionEditor {

    public JFileOpener() { //Here
        super();
    }

    private final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File(".")) {
        @Override
        protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent) throws HeadlessException {
            JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);
            dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            return dialog;
        }
    };

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return this;
    }

    public void edit(ConfigField field) {
        setText(Strings.fileName((String) field.get()));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            if (this.fc.showOpenDialog(null) != 0)
                return;
            field.set(this.fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            setText(Strings.fileName((String) field.get()));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did not work, on my other pc the original one worked fine,just on this pc that didn't work :(

Comment: i realy need help, because the original code, works fine on all pcs ! just not on this one